# update a Model field in DetailView

Tags: django, forms, django-models, detailview

As a newbie in Django, I'm sure there is something obvious I'm not seeing.  I have a user model with a one to one relationship to a userprofile model, where I'm storing the profile photo.  I mixed DetailView and Formview because I want the user to go to his details page and update just the photo, but somehow its not working for me.  I know I could do the job with UpdateView, but for didactic purposes, can anyone tell me why this is not working? I'm trying to updated the model fields in the form_valid method but this is not working, they just remain with the old values. I thought at the beginning it was the photo that could not be updated because of some errors on my side, but I've tried also updating other string fields and it doesnt work.  Here the code: (the commented out fields are the places where I tried updating several model fields using get_object_or_404 and other functions)

```
class UserDetail(FormMixin, DetailView):
template_name = "users/user_detail.html"
model = User
form_class = forms.UserPhotoForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('users:user_detail', args=[str(self.get_object().pk)])

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    user = self.get_object()
    form = forms.UserPhotoForm(instance=user)
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user_rating'] = CotizacionReview.objects.filter(cotizacion__user=self.get_object()).aggregate(Avg('nota'))
    context['form'] = form
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(UserDetail, self).form_valid(form)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    a = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.get_object().id).userprofile
    form = forms.UserPhotoForm(request.FILES['avatar'], instance=a)
    # get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.get_object().id).apellido = '1234'
    if form.is_valid():
        # print(get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.get_object().id).userprofile.avatar) 
        # I tried updating several model fields here, but didnt work
        # print(request.FILES['avatar'])
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**Here the model:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user   = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='profile_pics/default-user-icon-4.jpg', blank=True)
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
apellido = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
link = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
educacion = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
experiencia = models.TextField(max_length=512, blank=True)
birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)

def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I achieved it by using commit=False in my form_valid method:

```
class UserDetail(FormMixin, DetailView):
template_name = "users/user_detail.html"
model = User
form_class = forms.UserPhotoForm

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('users:user_detail', args=[str(self.get_object().pk)])

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    user = self.get_object()
    form = forms.UserPhotoForm(instance=user)
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user_rating'] = CotizacionReview.objects.filter(cotizacion__user=self.get_object()).aggregate(Avg('nota'))
    context['form'] = form
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    user_instance =  form.save(commit=False)
    user_instance.avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
    user_instance.id = self.get_object().userprofile.id
    user_instance.save(update_fields=['avatar'])

    return super(UserDetail, self).form_valid(form)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

But now I have another problem.  Every time I update the photo, a new photo is saved to the database.  Is there a way of doing this and deleting the old photo? or replacing it?